# SQL JOIN not working the way i need

Tags: php, sql, join

Hi guys im have trouble with a SQL join statement. i cant seem to get it to work the way i want

```
ex.
TABLE1          TABLE 2 
ID  NAME        ID  INFO
1   JOE         1   YES
2   MIKE        1   NO
3   JESS        1   MAYBE
4   ROB         2   NO
                2   NO
```

```php
    $stid = oci_parse($conn, "  

                                SELECT * FROM TABLE1 TBL1 RIGHT JOIN TABLE2 TBL2 
ON (TBL1.ID = TBL2.ID0 WHERE TBL1.ID = '1'                          

                                ");
    oci_execute($stid);

while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_BOTH+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) != false) {

  echo $row['NAME']."<br/ >";
  echo $row['INFO']."<br/ >";

}
```

what i want to see is

```
RESULT

JOE
YES
NO
MAYBE
```

typically what i get (regardless of join type) is something  like

```
JOE
YES
JOE
NO
JOE
MAYBE
```

any help would be great.

Comment: From where comes `ID0` ?? or lets say the sql server screams: _sql syntax is not working the way i need_ , fix that first.

Comment: And that is what you will get - because that's how joins work.

Comment: By the way, RIGHT JOIN is an INNER JOIN actually the way you use it.

Comment: this is not actual code. i just created it for this example. lets pretend there are no syntax errors. can i accompish what i want with a join?

Comment: Of course mistaking a right join for a left join is not a syntax error, it is a logical error and does not help very much to clarify your problem. Anyway, since your problem is probably irrelevant, I have attempted an answer based on the expected output you provided.

Comment: This is not a place for pretend code.  If you don't have _actual_ code with an _actual_ problem, then go try something first and come back when you do.

Answer (score 0):

don't use rigth join, change it for **left join**

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 TBL1 LEFT JOIN TABLE2 TBL2 
ON (TBL1.ID = TBL2.ID) WHERE TBL1.ID = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to change the RIGHT JOIN to LEFT JOIN (or simple JOIN, check your requirements). Now for the main part of your problem: the JOIN works as expected, you need to use your favourite language to do something like that:

**Pseudocode**

```
var test_name = "";
var last_name = "";
while EXIST_MORE_RECORDS {
  test_name = $row['NAME'];
  if (test_name != last_name) {
    last_name = test_name;
    print last_name;
  }
  print $row['INFO']."<br/ >";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the results of your query:

```
+----+------+----+-------+
| ID | NAME | ID | INFO  |
+----+------+----+-------+
|  1 | JOE  |  1 | MAYBE |
|  1 | JOE  |  1 | NO    |
|  1 | JOE  |  1 | YES   |
+----+------+----+-------+
```

Now look at your loop.  You're outputting `NAME` and `INFO` for each row.  You could alter your loop like @giorgos-altanis suggests.

You could also change your query to use `UNION`, and grab the `NAME` and `INFO` separately so that each is its own row.

```
select Name VALUE, 0 sortorder
from TABLE1 
where ID = '1'
union
select Info VALUE, 1 sortorder
from TABLE2
where ID = '1'
order by sortorder
```

This would give you results like :

```
+-------+-----------+
| VALUE | sortorder |
+-------+-----------+
| JOE   |         0 |
| MAYBE |         1 |
| NO    |         1 |
| YES   |         1 |
+-------+-----------+
```

Then you could use a simple loop.  Hard to say whether this would be an appropriate solution to your *actual* code.

Note that the order of rows from Table2 cannot be guaranteed.  If you want them to appear in order of YES, NO, MAYBE, you'll need an additional field in the table to define the sort order (or maybe a `CASE` statement).

**UPDATE**

If all you want is the count of the rows from Table2 (which is a completely different question), then you just need to join the tables and then group on the `NAME`:

```
select TBL1.ID, TBL1.NAME, COUNT(1) TBL2COUNT
from TABLE1 TBL1
join TABLE2 TBL2 on TBL1.ID = TBL2.ID
where TBL1.ID = '1'
group by tbl1.ID, TBL1.NAME
```

Comment: to be honest what i actaully what the code to do is just COUNT() the number of rows returned from table2 and display the count. (EX. JOE COUNT INFO 3)

Comment: thank you - how come COUNT(1)? what is the 1 referencing? thank you for the help

Comment: 1 is just a non-null expression.  You can also use `COUNT(*)`.  Or `COUNT(TBL2.ID)`.  You can search this site for **COUNT(1) vs COUNT(*)** to find out more than you probably care to.